# Why does calling a function on an iterator that points to an object not let me change the object itself?

Tags: c++

I have a vector that contains **Enemy** objects called **enemiesOnField**. When calling a function **takeYourTurn** that potentially changes the coordinates of individual enemies I noticed that even though the change occurs within the function, it doesn't persist in the **enemiesOnField** vector. This leads me to believe that when calling this function by iterator it is somehow called on a copy, not the original object. When calling by reference returned by the [] operator everything works normally.

The code that doesn't work as expected is commented out:

```
void World::letNPCsAct()
{

    /* this doesn't work
    for (auto it : enemiesOnField)      
        it.takeYourTurn();*/

    // this works
    for (int i = 0; i < enemiesOnField.size(); ++i)
        enemiesOnField[i].takeYourTurn();

}
```

Why is this like this??

Comment: Your range based loop modifies *copies* of the original objects. You need to loop over references to modify the original vector.

Comment: So something like:

 for (const auto& it : enemiesOnField)      
        it.takeYourTurn();

Would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range-for loop gives you the *objects* contained in the range, not iterators to them.

```
for (auto it : enemiesOnField)      
    it.takeYourTurn();
```

This is not calling `takeYourTurn` through an iterator.  It is calling it on a *copy* of the object contained in `enemiesOnField`.

If you want it to use references, you must declare it to do so:

```
for (auto& enemy : enemiesOnField)      
    enemy.takeYourTurn();
```

---

The range-for you used is semantically equivalent to the following:

```
{
    auto&& __range = enemiesOnField;
    auto __begin = __range.begin();
    auto __end = __range.end();
    for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        auto it = *__begin;
        it.takeYourTurn();
    }
}
```

(Note that the names `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are for exposition only.  Those objects cannot be referenced by user code)

Note that `auto it = *__begin` makes a *copy* of the object referenced by `__begin`.

Answer (score 2):

Normal for loop works because you are directly changing the content. Range based for loop creates copies by default. So your content won't be modified. If you want to modify, you need to use the reference as below.

```
for (auto& it: enemiesOnField) {    
    it.takeYourTurn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cpp
for (auto& it: enemiesOnField) {    
    it.takeYourTurn();
}
```

You need to iterate through references.