# using a range-based for-loop to iterate through a list of pointers

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

Good day everyone,

I have been trying the following code to reset all pointers in a list to nullptr as shown below:

```
    for (auto item : { ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 })
        item = nullptr;
```

the problem is that a copy of the pointer is made to item, so the original ptrs are unequal to nullptr at the end.

I would like to get some sort of reference to the pointers themselves or maybe there is already a better alternative to setting all pointers in a container to nullptr. If any of you happen to work with Qt maybe there's a good way of doing it in Qt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make `ptr1`, `ptr2`, and `ptr3` be elements of a container of some sort instead of distinct variables.

Comment: try `auto& item`

Comment: does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899291/why-does-calling-a-function-on-an-iterator-that-points-to-an-object-not-let-me-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AlanBirtles That doesn't work, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279834/using-a-range-based-for-loop-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-pointers#comment113667353_64279937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get some sort of reference

You're creating a `std::initializer_list` with that braced init list. Unfortunately, such list always contains copies and you cannot assign to the variables used to initialise it through that list.

You could use reference wrappers:

```
for (auto ref : { std::ref(ptr1), std::ref(ptr2), std::ref(ptr3) })
    ref.get() = nullptr;
```

---

If you used an array of pointers instead of separate variables, then iterating over them would be trivial:

```
T* ptrs[3];
for (auto& ptr : ptrs})
    ptr = nullptr;
```

Comment: In the 1st example, you could alternatively use pointer-to-pointer elements instead, and then you don't have to involve any overhead with `reference_wrapper`, eg: `for (auto item : { &ptr1, &ptr2, &ptr3 }) *item = nullptr;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau What overhead? It's just a class that contains a pointer.

Comment: The overhead of making a function call that constructs and returns an object, and all the compiler processing needed to parse the various templates being used by `reference_wrapper` internally.  Whereas a raw pointer is, well, a raw pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is no overhead from function calls that are expanded inline though.

Comment: I still feel like it is just overkill in this example. But whatever.  Multiple solutions to the same problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That I agree. `ptr1 = ptr2 = ptr3 = nullptr;` suggested by dfri is much better.

Comment: This answer helped me the most in the sense that it explained what the actual root of my problem was. However, the answer by @dfri also helped and therefore got an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

If you are typing the individual pointer variables out, why not just use a chained assignment?

```
ptr1 = ptr2 = ptr3 = nullptr;  // All three pointers are nullptr.
```

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OhcdejCHOie3JCYf).

---

> [...] or maybe there is already a better alternative to setting all pointers in a container to `nullptr`.

If you have your pointers in an actual containers as compared to separate, named pointer variables, you can use a range-based for loop to write to and read the pointer elements of the container:

```
#include <array>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

// Container of 'pointer-to-const-int' elements.
using MyPointersArray = std::array<int const*, 3>;

void inspectNullptrness(const MyPointersArray& arr) {
    for (const auto& p : arr) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha 
            << (p == nullptr) << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    MyPointersArray pointers{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
    const int a = 42;
    inspectNullptrness(pointers); // true true true
    
    // Set pointers.
    for(auto& p : pointers) { p = &a; }
    inspectNullptrness(pointers); // false false false
    
    // Reset pointers.
    for(auto& p : pointers) { p = nullptr; }
    inspectNullptrness(pointers); // true true true
}
```